# Vimeo api /me doesn´t return upload_quota value

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to check my own upload quota.
[As described in docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#check-user-quota), I use  `GET https://api.vimeo.com/me`
API response doesn´t return expected value:

> In the response, find the **upload_quota** object, look for the space
>   object inside it, and check the value.

Has API changed? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things is happening:

- Your API app has not yet been granted upload permission. To request upload access, visit your app's management page at https://developer.vimeo.com/apps, click on "Request Upload Access", and fill out the request form.
- If your API app already has upload permission, the token used to authenticate the request may not have the upload scope. When a token lacks the upload scope, upload-related metadata like the upload_quota array will not return.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Thanks Tommy, it might be that request is still pending, tks!